# Swift 4, How can I remove VC from memory?

Tags: swift

Image :

[image]

I am using a navigation controller like the image I uploaded.
And I have 4 VC in the navigation controller. 
On VC 4 I have to use a lot of momerys so I want to delete the previous VC from the memory. I used 'weak' on every @IBOutlet.

I am using 100mb on 1 VC and when I go to 2 VC the memory goes up to 200mb. And when I come back to VC 1 the memory doesn't come down to 100mb, it is still 200mb. 
Is there a way to remove all of the VC 2 from memory?

Comment: It may mean that you have a Memory Leak. If you use async calls, and call self in the closure, check that you use `[weak self]`, a `(NS)Timer` could also be a source for memory leak. Use Intruments Memory Leak took.

Comment: One more thing to check is the `dealloc`(objc)/`deinit`(swift) method on each UIViewController. If these are not called you might have retain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Views will no be deallocated when they are still in the navigation stack. Not even when you declared them as `weak`. You can do some deallocation tricks yourself, like implement some detach logic in the `viewDidDissapear` by setting some heavy properties to `nil` and attach them again in the `viewDidAppear`.

Besides of that, check if you are not hold a reference somewhere in your hierarchy to some heavy resources. Because 100MB per view really is a lot.